# Check that an object's class is contained in a specific package and cast it

Tags: java, java-8

I have a java code (java 8) that call a service returning an object (class Foo)

The Foo class is inherited by child classes (FooChild1, FooChild2 ... contained in a package, named "packageFoo") and other child classes.

I have an id on FooChildX (from packageFoo).

I want to retrieve the id on the object if its class is a child class of Foo.
I can't modify the service or edit the Foo class (or child classes)

I've extracted the list of classes present in packageFoo. I'm using the method on baeldung site for the extraction :

```
 public Set<Class> findAllClassesUsingClassLoader(String packageName) {
    InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
      .getResourceAsStream(packageName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    return reader.lines()
      .filter(line -> line.endsWith(".class"))
      .map(line -> getClass(line, packageName))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private Class getClass(String className, String packageName) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(packageName + "."
          + className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.')));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I can't perform instanceof and cast on my extracted list

```
for(Class obj : classesList){
        if(entry instanceof obj ) {
           (obj) entry
        }
}
```

I don't want specifying every class in my package to keep light maintainability if possible.

```
if(entry instanceof FooChild1) {...} 
if(entry instanceof FooChild2) {...}
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: `if(obj.isAssignableFrom(entry.getClass()))` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Note that getting a list of entries from `getResourceAsStream` for a package is not a guaranteed behavior. This may work in the development environment and break in production, depending on the form of deployment. Consider using [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) instead. But you are also confusing classes and objects. A `Class` object is not an instance of your class, hence you can’t use `instanceof`, neither can you “retrieve the id on(sic) the object”, as there is no object, only a class. And a `Set` is not a `List`.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS sorry but it's didn't work for me, the bool is always false

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the warning. I wil check ServiceLoader

Answer (score 0):

```java
public Set<Class<?>> findAllClassesUsingClassLoader(String packageName) {}
```

If what you want to do is test whether or not `FooChildX` actual type is `Foo` or a subtype, you've got it:

```java
FooChildX.class.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class);
```

---

There's a framework [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) you can use it to do it very easily:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Set<Class<? extends FooChild>> classes = findAllClasses("foo", FooChild.class);

    for (Class<?> cls : classes) {
        // do smth
    }
}

public static <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> findAllClasses(String packageName, Class<T> cls) {
    return new Reflections(packageName).getSubTypesOf(cls);
}
```